# Create XML with XMLBUILDER2 in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm creating an XML file using a foreach to add the data.

Problem:

I need to create an ELEMENT < Listings > and inside it I need to put the children that will be Listing given .... < /Listing > and after that FOR I need to close the < /Listings >

What is happening is that it is creating the xml file with the Listings element already closed example: < Listings/ >

Code:

```
var xml = builder.create('ListingDataFeed', { version: '1.0', encoding: "UTF-8"});

    xml.ele('Listings');

    // var listings = xml.ele('Listings');
    for(var i=0; i< result.length; i++){

        xml.ele('Listing')

        .ele('ListingID', `${result[i].sku}`).up()
        .ele('Title').dat(`${result[i].name}`).up()
        .ele('TransactionType', `${transaction}`).up()
        .ele('PublicationType', `${type_offer}`).up()
        .ele('DetailViewUrl', 'https://sortinvestimentos.com.br/imovel/' + `${result[i].url}`).up()
        .ele('Media')
            .ele('Item', {'medium': 'image'}, `${result[i].media_1}`).up()
        .up() // Media finish
        .ele('ContactInfo')
            .ele('Name', 'Sort Investimentos').up()
            .ele('Email', 'contato@sortinvestimentos.com.br').up()
        .up()
    .up() // Listing finish
    }
    .up(); // Listings finish

    var root = xml.end({ pretty: true});
```

This result

[image]

Comment: `let listings = xml.ele('Listing'); for(...) { Listings.ele('Listing')..}.`.

Comment: And where do I put it after

Comment: What I mean is that when you add your "listing" element, you should append it to the "Listings" element, not to the "xml" element which is the root. So you assign the listings element to a variable, than you can append to it inside the loop. That's how it is shown in the docs: https://oozcitak.github.io/xmlbuilder2/node-creation-functions.html#ele

Comment: Can you be more detailed? Answer with the code mentioned in the middle of the question code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
var {create} = require("xmlbuilder2");
const R = [{name: 'foo1', sku: 'bar1'}, {name:'foo2', sku: 'bar2'}];
let xml = create({ version: '1.0', encoding: "UTF-8"})
    .ele('ListingDataFeed')
    .ele('Listings');
for(let i = 0; i<R.length;i++){
 xml.ele("Listing")
    .ele("listingId: ", `${R[i].sku}`).up()
    .ele('Title').dat(`${R[i].name}`).up().up();
        //rest of your code
}
```

The point being that the `ele()` function creates a new node **and returns that node**. Therefore, when you call your loop, you have to make sure that the `xml` variable is pointing to the `Listings` node, so the child elements are attached to it.
In the code above, at the beginning of the loop, the `xml` var is pointing the newly created `Listings` element.

Comment: I go to execute this code, after i'm back to say the result